# C++ OOP registering callback function (typedef issue)

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

Basically I am trying to pack OpenNI Kinect into RT-middleware framework.
The OpenNI Kinect uses callback and has to be registered.

To do this, I could declare the callback functions and relevant variables in global without problem.

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// Global
// ----------------------------------------------
// Declare OpenNI nodes
xn::Context g_Context;
xn::ScriptNode g_scriptNode;
xn::DepthGenerator g_DepthGenerator;
xn::UserGenerator g_UserGenerator;
// ... more codes

// Define callback functions
// Callback: New user was detected
void User_NewUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    // ... some codes
    if (g_bNeedPose)
    {
        g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(g_strPose, nId);
    }
    // ... some codes
}

// Callback: An existing user was lost
void User_LostUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    // ... some codes
}

// -----------------------------------------------
// Member
// ----------------------------------------------
// Register callback functioins in the RT-middleware class (OOP)
RTC::ReturnCode_t rtc_kinect::onActivated(RTC::UniqueId ec_id)
{
    // ... some codes
    nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.RegisterUserCallbacks(User_NewUser, User_LostUser, NULL, hUserCallbacks);
    // ... some codes
}
```

The above worked.  However, using global variables and functions, I was told, is inappropriate.

I tried to move the callback functions and related variables as member of the middleware class, however been unsuccessful.  The codes are:

```
// ----------------------------------------
// private members
// ----------------------------------------
// Declare OpenNI nodes as member variables
xn::Context g_Context;
xn::ScriptNode g_scriptNode;
xn::DepthGenerator g_DepthGenerator;
xn::UserGenerator g_UserGenerator;
// ... more codes

// Define callback functions as member function
// Callback: New user was detected
void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE rtc_kinect::User_NewUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    // ... some codes
    if (g_bNeedPose)
    {
        g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(g_strPose, nId);
    }
    else
    {
        g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RequestCalibration(nId, TRUE);
    }
}

// Callback: An existing user was lost
void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE rtc_kinect::User_LostUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    // ... some codes
}


// Register callback functioins in the RT-middleware class
RTC::ReturnCode_t rtc_kinect::onActivated(RTC::UniqueId ec_id)
{
    // ... some codes
    nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.RegisterUserCallbacks(&rtc_kinect::User_NewUser, &rtc_kinect::User_LostUser, NULL, hUserCallbacks);
    // ... some codes
}
```

The following errors were reported by the compiler:

```
error C2664: 'xn::UserGenerator::RegisterUserCallbacks' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__stdcall rtc_kinect::* )(xn::UserGenerator &,XnUserID,void *)' to 'xn::UserGenerator::UserHandler'
error C2664: 'xn::PoseDetectionCapability::RegisterToPoseDetected' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__stdcall rtc_kinect::* )(xn::PoseDetectionCapability &,const XnChar *,XnUserID,void *)' to 'xn::PoseDetectionCapability::PoseDetection'
.... and many more
```

This is one example of the definition of the callback registration function:

```
inline XnStatus RegisterUserCallbacks(UserHandler NewUserCB, UserHandler LostUserCB, void* pCookie, XnCallbackHandle& hCallback)
{
    // ... some codes
}
```

This an example of the typedef of the parameter 1:

```
typedef void (XN_CALLBACK_TYPE* UserHandler)(UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID user, void* pCookie);
```

My development platform is MS Visual Studio 2008.
Being novice, I cannot resolve the problem.  Hopeful for any help.

Comment: As [briefly mentioned below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063476/594137), you would do well to read [\[33\] Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callbacks are meant to be pointers-to-functions.  You're trying to use pointers-to-member-functions.  They aren't the same thing. (From the comp.lang.c++ FAQ: [Is the type of "pointer-to-member-function" different from "pointer-to-function"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.1)). Member functions need to operate on an *object* of that class.

You can resolve your compilation error if you make your functions `static` class methods instead.

Incidentally, you didn't really do much to avoid using global variables. *That* is the real problem; it doesn't matter so much whether your callback functions are in the global scope or not (especially since you could put them in an anonymous namespace or use the `static` keyword to limit them to only that file's compilation unit).  Note that using `static` member variables isn't really any different from using globals.

I'm not familiar with this SDK, but you probably should pack whatever information you need into a `struct` or `class` and presumably pass around pointer to it through that `void* pCookie` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply, I will get on this matter when back to work desk and try the static matter as well as read up Styne's link, PS: I didn't get any notification on reply to my post (new with this), and my apology that I had re-posted this question in another forum.  I will get back here after I do some try.  Thanks again.

Comment: jamesdlin, styne666, thanks for the pointers! I now see the problem, although I don't know how to solve it.  Ya, static works however the associated variables will have to be static/global, i.e. static function cannot access member variables (just learned).  The whole thing doesn't differ much from using global.  I am now searching to learn how to wrap (struct or class) to do the job; completely blank currently.  Hope to find something useful in the ocean (ya, bigger than sea) of internet.  Any pointer will be very much appreciated.  Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @hong: As I mentioned, you probably want to pass around a pointer to a `struct`/`class` containing your variables for that `pCookie` parameter.  It's a typical practice when registering callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on that; much appreciated.  I noted your suggestion, however do not have the capability to implement it (yet).  I am searching/reading (blindly) around to learn how to do it ... As a matter of fact, I cannot figure out how the pCookie is used; I thought the function is being passed in as UserHandle.  I know I am missing a lot of points and have a lot to figure out, sigh.